# TFS 2012 disable web access

Tags: tfs

How can we **disable** web access to my Team Foundation Server 2012? 
I don't want it to be accessible from web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no idea why you would want to do this, but I suppose you could turn it off in IIS.

Comment: A large portion of the administration features at the collection level are in Web Access, so yes I'm serious.

Comment: I'm not using that "large portion of features". I'm looking for simple "On/Off web access" feature in TFS, turning off IIS website will make source control inaccessible from Visual Studio Source Control Explorer won't?

Comment: You can't turn off web access. It is an integral part of managing your TFS Server and workflow. This isn't possible. It's like asking if you could turn of the control panel.